# can we adjust the transparency of drawn line on when mouse move on it?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I need your help , my question is can we adjust the transparency of drawn line on mouse move??

I wrote this code to draw tow lines and I added the addEventListener to get the coordinates of mouse but my problem is that I do not know how to adjust the transparency when the mouse is moving on the line.

```
<body>

    <canvas id="drawImage" width="900" height="900" style="background-color:black"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var canvas  = document.getElementById("drawImage");
        var cont = canvas.getContext("2d");
        cont.beginPath();
        cont.lineWidth=15;
        cont.strokeStyle="red";
        cont.moveTo(0,0);
        cont.lineTo(100,100);
        cont.stroke();
        cont.save();
        cont.beginPath();
        cont.strokeStyle="yellow";
        cont.moveTo(100,100);
        cont.lineTo(100,150);
        cont.stroke();
        cont.save();

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event {});


    </script>
</body>
```

thanx every body.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that alters transparency with each stroke using `.globalAlpha`

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/dQFvm/

[image]

Example function:

```
function drawAlphaLine(x0,y0,x1,y1,strokeColor,alpha){        
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x0,y0);
        ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
        ctx.globalAlpha=alpha;
        ctx.strokeStyle=strokeColor;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
}
```